# How to import SP self signed certificate to OpenAm tomcat server for digital signature validation?

Tags: tomcat7, single-sign-on, keystore, openam

I have an Enterprise App which is acting as SP(Service Provider) and an OpenAm app acting as IdP(Identity Provider).
In SP, I have created a self-signed certificate for digital signature to communicate with OpenAM for SSO.

SP digitally signs and initiates the request, but In OpenAm i am getting 'The SAML Request is invalid' error. I think this is because of the absence of certificate in OpenAM tomcat server.

I have already tried [creating the Key Store and adding my Self Signed certificate to it](https://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-configure-tomcat-to-support-ssl-or-https/).

**Questions**

1. How to import SP self-signed certificate in tomcat for digital signature validation?
2. How validation is happening in OpenAm?

Answer (score 0):

Check yr openam config directory (eg ~/openam/openam). This directory contains the keystore file used by OpenAM.

> keytool -list -keystore ~/openam13/openam/keystore.jks

Comment: the SAML keystore/truststure configured in OpenAM is not used to verify the digital signature ,but the public key incuded in the certificate of the SP's meta data imported into OpenAM